# Get Month as well as date in my variable - javascript

Tags: javascript, date, if-statement

Hi i am trying to do a IF statement which allows the current date to be compared to the input date.. if the input date is below the current date it will be false.

I have got the date passing through my variable but it only stores the number so for example it compares day 9 to another day, which is not very reliable. I want the variable to take in the month and the year as well, meaning it can compare the ENTIRE DATE.

If there is a better way let me know.

Here is my code

```
if (this.element.find('#visitdate').length > 0) {
  var dateParts = $('#visitdate').val().split('/');
  var check = new Date(dateParts[2], dateParts[1], dateParts[0], 0,0,0,0).getDate();
  var today = new Date().getDate;
  if (check < today) {
    _errMsg = "Please enter a furture visit date";
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the value of `visitdate`

Comment: It is the input from the user

Answer (score 0):

Your line for today's date contains an error:

```
var today = new Date().getDate;
```

should be

```
var today = new Date().getDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

format as `mm/dd/yyyy`
    var from = '08/19/2013 00:00'
    var to = '08/12/2013 00:00 '
    var today = new Date().getDate();

```
function isFromBiggerThanTo(dtmfrom, dtmto){
var from = new Date(dtmfrom).getTime();
var to = new Date(dtmto).getTime() ;
return from >= to ;
}
```

or using below

```
var x = new Date('2013-05-23');
var y = new Date('2013-05-23');
```

and compare

Answer (score 0):

You can try this - it's working fine in my project -

- **Step 1**

> First Create javascript function as below.

- `Date.prototype.DaysBetween = function () {
          var intMilDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
          var intMilDif = arguments[0] - this;
          var intDays = Math.floor(intMilDif / intMilDay);
          if (intDays.toLocaleString() == "NaN") {
              return 0;
          }
          else {
              return intDays + 1;
          }
      }`

**Step 2**
 - 
`var check = new Date(dateParts[2], dateParts[1], dateParts[0], 0,0,0,0).getDate();
  var today = new Date().getDate;
  var dateDiff = check .DaysBetween(today); 
// it will return integer value (difference between two dates )
if(dateDiff > 0 ){ alert('Your message.......');}`

Answer (score 0):

You can have this much easier.

You dont need to check with getDate() property you can just compare 2 dates.

And also is not needed to initialize with hours, minutes and seconds the Date, you only need year, month and date.

Here you have your example simplified

```
  var dateParts = $('#visitdate').val().split('/');
  var check = new Date(dateParts[2], dateParts[1], dateParts[0]);
  var today = new Date();
  if (check < today) {        
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wns3LkLv/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var user="09/09/2014/5/30";
 var arrdt= user.split("/");
 var userdt = new Date(arrdt[2], arrdt[1] - 1, arrdt[0],arrdt[3],arrdt[4]);
 var currdt = new Date();
 if (userdt < currdt) {
     alert("userdate is before current date"); //do something
 }else{
      alert("userdate is after current date");  //do something
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers guys i have fixed it.

I used the getTime function instead of getDate.
Then the check variable had to have a -1 assigned to the month as it was going 1 month to high.

```
var check = new Date(dateParts[2], dateParts[1]-1, dateParts[0], 0,0,0,0).getTime();
```

Cheers